# DIV Slide to the left and stay on top

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/volkanbygl/mq2c2129/1/)  link to what I am trying to accomplish... When I click on the right side Div, it slides to the left, but how do I make it stay on top of the left div... so it is visible ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#right").click(function(){
   $("#right").toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
  });
});
```

Also, how do I put third DIV under the right side DIV, so it is revealed when the right side div is moved to the left...

thanks!!

Comment: Note that you're using `toggle`. This means that you are making the element disappear - it's not just moving to the left.

Comment: aaah thanks! so what do I use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with 2 floating div like this :

```
#left{
    background-color: red;
    width:50%;
    height:150px;
    float: left;
}
#right{
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
    height:150px;
    float: left;
}
```

The moving div has an absolute positioning to be always over the 2 floating div, and a transition property to manage the sliding effect :

```
#moving{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width:50%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 150px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

For the absolute positioned div, we need the wrapper div to be relative positioned :

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And then we add a class for the top left position :

```
#moving.left{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

The javascript has just to toggle the moving div "left" class when clicking on it, the sliding effect being managed with CSS transition property :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#moving").click(function(){
      $("#moving").toggleClass("left");
   });
});
```

See this fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/mq2c2129/5/

Answer (score 1):

To conserve in top you must to remove float and put absolute positioning:

```
   #right, #left {
       position :absolute;
       top: 0;
   }
```

## EDIT

With a better explanation, can try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#right").click(function(){
       $("#right").animate({left: 0}, 500);
    });
 });
```

CSS

```
 #right {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     z-index:1 ;
 }
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mq2c2129/2/

Comment: Then, what do you need?

Comment: I need two divs, side by side. If I click on the right side div, it moves to the left, and reveals another div below...